# What is "low code"?

Tags: development-process

Recently I have come across [this](http://sdtimes.com/guest-view-five-reasons-low-code-development-no-longer-optional/) article, which claims that "low-code" development is very important in the rapidly changing world of software engineering. I got the idea that "low-code" has something to do with high-level programming and small sized code, but without a formal definition of what it actually is, the concept remains quite vague in my mind. So, since I couldn't find a question relating to this concept here (hope I didn't miss anything), I thought I'd ask the specialists:

- What is the formal definition for low-code development (if exists)?
- Does it refer to a specific set of programing languages, or is it just a general concept / set of guidelines on how to write software?

Comment: [Forrester Research defines a low-code development platform as follows: *platforms that enable rapid application delivery with a minimum of hand-coding, and quick setup and deployment, for systems of engagement.*](https://www.mendix.com/think-tank/low-code-development-answers-business-needs/)  That's a lot of buzzwords, and frankly I think it's just another marketing term, but your guy is right; it's not a new idea, just a different name (the old name was "Rapid Application Development.")  "Low code" just means **"A low amount of code,"** that's all.

Comment: In this kind of program, the only focus is data. No processes are represented, so the user ends up being the program, and the software is a means to store data for the program in the user's head. Now try to train a new hire to use that "software".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Low code gives users the ability to make modifications to an application with little or no code.

An example would be of a GUI interface that allowed the drawing of data form objects (text box, list box, check box and labels), link them to a table and allow CRUD all without the "user" writing any code or maybe they write a formula or two for calculations and/or data check. Of course the builders of the application have to create all of this capability. Microsoft Access is an example of having low code capabilities even though, it has a lot of other full coding features as well. Salesforce.com offers this in a web app.

The idea is to empower those that are more familiar with the business side of the application to make modifications without being a programmer. I personally like the idea of taking off mundane development tasks off of my plate. Users like it because they can have changes made faster without bothering the IT department. Of course there are limitations (Unless you build it very, very well.) on the functionality they have at their disposal along with many coding practices (source/version control, tests, performance, etc.).

Comment: Despite the fact that we've had tools like this for literally decades, the state of the art of modern software development has drifted *away* from using them.  Most modern software development is very code-centric, and I don't see that changing any time soon, unless the next generation of visual tools becomes really compelling.

Comment: And you're right; the audience for such tools is business analysts for the most part, not software developers.  We'll see if it catches on or not; I eagerly await the next generation of applications with 300 controls on a single form, and one database table backing it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In my experience these tools are managed by business users until they've painted themselves into a corner.  Then developers are brought in to untangle a gigantic mess of unreliable buggy garbage with gobs of unnecessary complexity.  These tools lack things that any decent development platform would have (because they aren't made for developers) and usually require opening lots of little dialogs in order to make the same change in 5000 different places.  Also, they use source files that no merge tool can make sense with so team development is a nightmare.

Comment: And yet they're now being held up as the next "silver bullet," and even given a new marketing term.  Hooray for enterprise!

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was recently at a demo where a vendor sales creature was showing how we could create a restful service with "zero lines of code" (except for the xpath he typed in but there was no line return so must not count).  At some point the service plopped up a nice detailed stack trace in the browser which is the default behavior on error.  I pleaded with the vendor to not make a security no-no default behavior for the good of humanity.  I'm not holding my breath.  This is one of the biggest problems with these tools. The users are clueless about the implications of what they are doing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  But think of the synergies you'll be able to leverage by enabling low-code applications in your enterprise cloud.  :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - There is a massive amount of what would have been programmed software being done in Excel.

Comment: @JeffO: I never mentioned Excel.

Comment: Isn't that the same as RAD?

Comment: It's the 90's all over again.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova: Yeah I was thinking this is good old RAD rebranded (4th gen 5th gen and all that).

Comment: @BaselShishani how are the 1st, 2nd, 3rd rebranding versions called?